# Setting VPN domain Windows 10

Tags: windows, vpn, windows-10, domain

On step 10 of https://www.my-private-network.co.uk/windows-7-pptp-setup/ it has a place to enter a domain (of which I need according to instructions by my workplace) but on windows 10 I have no way to enter in a domain:

[image]

It simply will not let me type anything into the domain field to specify the domain. What do I do to specify the domain?

Comment: The document to which you've linked states explicitly that you should not use a domain when connecting to its service.

Answer (score 2):

You could try to type the domain name in from of your username, appended by a backslash, like this:

Username: `domain\username` or with two backslashes in front of it: `\\domain\username\`

Comment: This is the way Windows has moved since Windows 7 to increase security I think. It's easier to target a network if you know a bit of information - even the domain name!